# How to show the set is a vector space with the given operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

The set is all ordered pairs of real numbers with the operations (*x, y*) + (*x', y'*) = (*y + y', x + x'*) and *k*(*x, y*) = (*kx, ky*) for all real numbers *k*.

I know I must show that the 10 axioms that define a vector space hold, but I am confused by the behavior given for vector addition in this example.

I take this to mean that if I let **u** = (*x, y*) and **v** = (*x', y'*), then **u** + **v** = (*y + y', x + x'*). But what does this say about the commutative and associative properties of these vectors?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.  Commutative is fine, but I highly doubt it will be associative and it should be easy to find a counterexample by trying random inputs.